# Link Azure AD B2C login user to custom database table user

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm pretty new to Azure AD and I could get the AD login working with username and password after setting client IDs, Domain and SignupSignin policies. My question is that is it possible to intercept this sign up and associate that user details with our own custom table in an external database? So that we could add more properties to those table while AD only keeps minimum data to keep the login working (even with social identities).

So behind the scenes after we get a token we query the additional user details from that external database which also has other business related data.

Any guide is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom policies and in the signup/sign in flow, call a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) to do whatever you want.

If you are using user flows, call an [API connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-user-flow). This [may](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-user-flow#where-you-can-enable-an-api-connector-in-a-user-flow) give you what you want.